# Upgrade paypal extension in magento

Tags: magento, paypal

i want to `upgrade only PayPal module in magento` is it possible to upgrade `only PayPal module?` Any help will be appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple 
You have to install the below extension

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-payment-fee-3194.html
```